# Lsqr first iteration with no initial guess

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am trying to solve

```
argmin||W_vector*FT^-1(Ax)-W_vector*B||
```

using lsqr with a function handle and without any initial guess (W_vector is a weighting vector). I thought that lsqr would have performed the first step computing x by C'b (call C=W*FT^-1(A)) using the vector b=W_vector.*B I passed to the function. This is the code:

```
b=W_vector.*B;
[x, flag]=lsqr(@(x1,modo)FUNC(x1,W_vector,A,modo),b,tol,maxit);


function [result, modo]=FUNC(x1,W_vector,A,modo)
    %Computes y=A*x for modo='notransp'
    %Computes y=A'*x for modo='transp'

    switch modo

        case 'notransp'
            res=A*x1;
            R1=reshape(res,norient,dim(1)*dim(2)*dim(3));
            for co=1:norient
                R2(:,:,:,co)=reshape(R1(co,:),dim(1),dim(2),dim(3));
                FR(:,:,:,co)=ifftn(R2(:,:,:,co));
                aux=FR(:,:,:,co);
                R3(co,:)=aux(:).';
            end
            result=W_vector.*R3(:);

        case 'transp'
            R1=reshape(x1./(W_vector+eps),norient,dim(1)*dim(2)*dim(3));
            for co=1:norient
                R2(:,:,:,co)=reshape(R1(co,:),dim(1),dim(2),dim(3));
                FR(:,:,:,co)=fftn(R2(:,:,:,co));
                aux=FR(:,:,:,co);
                R3(co,:)=aux(:).';
            end
            result=A'*R3(:);
    end
end
```

When I checked the result of `R1=reshape(x1./(W_vector+eps),norient,dim(1)*dim(2)*dim(3));` in case `'transp'` in the first iteration, I found out that x1 is not equal to b (after reshape, they are images, so I can see that look qualitatively the same but with very different values). I would like to understand how lsqr works because I am having some problems with weightings. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean "how it works" ? mathematically or in MATLAB? you seem to know how it works with MATLAB.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I would like to understand how the algorithm makes the first step. I thought it would have used b to compute x for the first time, i.e. I thought that x1 would have been exactly the vector b I passed to lsqr, but it seems to use something else.

Comment: So, you are saying that with the x you get, `norm(FUNC(x,W_vector,A,'trasn')-b)` is big? Have you tried checking the 3rd, 4th and 5th output from `lsqr`? they give some insigth of what could have happened